# Commutant built from the Unilateral Shift

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $T: \ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$ be the unilateral shift, and let $\mathcal{T}= \{ I, T, T^* \}$.

Show that $\mathcal{T}' = \{\lambda I_{\ell^2}  : \lambda \in \mathbb{C} \}$ and $\mathcal{T}'' = B(\ell^2)$.

Attempt:

Since $T$ is the unilateral shift, we have that $Te_n = e_{n+1}$.

Also, by definition, we have $\mathcal{T}' = \{ S \in B(\ell^2) : ST =TS, \forall T \in \mathcal{T}\}$.

Let's look at the each element in $T$:

We know that the identity $I$ always has the property $IS=SI$ for $S \in B(\ell^2) $.

Also, let $S \in B(\ell^2)$. Then we have  $STe_n= Se_{n+1} =e_{n+1 }S= Te_n S = TSe_{n}$.

For $T^*$, I know that $T^*e_n= e_{n-1}$, for $n>1$. So don't we get a similar result as above, i.e $ST^*e_n =T^* S e_n$?

So I'm a bit confused on how to get the results we want. I feel like I got the definitions of $\mathcal{T}'$ and $\mathcal{T}''$ mixed up somewhere...

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observing that, for every $n\geq 1$, one has that $Te_n=e_{n+1}$, and
$$
  T^*e_n = \left\{\matrix{0, & \text {if } n=1, \cr e_{n-1}, & \text {if } n>1, }\right.
  $$
one quicky sees that
$$
  (I-TT^*)e_n = \left\{\matrix{e_1, & \text {if } n=1, \cr 0, & \text {otherwise.} }\right.
  $$
So we deduce that the operator $P$ defined by
$$
  P:=I-TT^*
  $$
is the orthogonal projection onto the  space spanned by $e_1$.

If $S$ is any operator commuting with $T$ and $T^*$,  then obviously $S$ also  commutes with $P$, so
$$
  Se_1 = SPe_1 = PSe_1 =  \lambda e_1,
  $$
for some scalar $\lambda $.   We then claim that $S$ necessarily coincides with $\lambda I$, the reason being that for all $n>1$,
$$
  Se_n = ST^{n-1}e_1 = T^{n-1}Se_1 = \lambda T^{n-1}e_1 = \lambda e_n.
  $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If an operator commutes with the the unilateral shift and its adjoint, then it commutes with the whole [Toeplitz algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_algebra). Furthermore, the Toeplitz algebra contains all the compact operators.

If you don't want to appeal to such facts, I would suggest showing by hand that the algebra generated by the unilateral shift and its adjoint contains every operator whose matrix with respect to the standard basis of $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ has only finitely many nonzero entries. Basically, figure out how to construct the matrix $E_{ij}$ which has a $1$ in the $(i,j)$ position and zeros elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Let's rename $E=\{I,T,T^*\}$. If we show that $E'=\mathbb{C}I$, then the claim that $E''=\mathbb{B}(\ell^2)$ follows trivially, since $E''=(E')'=(\mathbb{C}I)'=\mathbb{B}(\ell^2)$.

> Lemma: Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathbb{K}(H)$ denote the compact operators over $H$. Then $\mathbb{K}(H)''=\mathbb{B}(H)$.

Proof: $\mathbb{K}(H)$ is a $C^*$-algebra that has an approximate unit of the form $\{p_\lambda\}$ where $p_\lambda$ are finite rank projections and $p_\lambda\to\text{id}_{H}$ in the strong operator topology. In other words, the inclusion $\mathbb{K}(H)\subset\mathbb{B}(H)$ is a non-degenerate representation, so, by von Neumann's double commutant theorem we have that
$$\mathbb{K}(H)''=\overline{\mathbb{K}(H)}^{sot}$$
But, in general, if $I$ is a closed, self-adjoint two sided ideal in $\mathbb{B}(H)$ then so is $\overline{I}^{sot}$: it is a $C^*$-algebra as we know that the strong closures of $C^*$-subalgebras are again $C^*$-algebras and it is an ideal since if $x\in \overline{I}^{sot}$ and $y\in\mathbb{B}(H)$ then we take a net $\{x_\mu\}\in I$ with $x_\mu\to x$ strongly and simply observe that $x_\mu y\in I$ for all $\mu$ and that $x_\mu y\to xy$ strongly, since multiplication is separately strongly continuous. Since $\mathbb{K}(H)$ is an ideal, its strong closure is an ideal and it contains the identity operator, since $p_\lambda\to\text{id}_{H}$. Thus it is equal to the entire algebra $\mathbb{B}(H)$, **q.e.d**.

Now it is elementary to check that $\mathbb{B}(\ell^2)'=\mathbb{C}I$, so $\mathbb{K}(\ell^2)'=\mathbb{K}(\ell^2)'''=\mathbb{B}(\ell^2)'=\mathbb{C}I$. It is also elementary to check that if $x\in E'$ then $x\in C^*(E)'$. So, if we show that $\mathbb{K}(\ell^2)\subset C^*(E)$, then $E'\subset C^*(E)'\subset\mathbb{K}(\ell^2)'=\mathbb{C}I$ and we will be done. Let's show this inclusion:

For $n\geq1$ define the projection $p_n\in\mathbb{B}(\ell^2)$ by
$$p_n(\xi_1,\xi_2,\dots)=(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n,0,0,\dots)$$
The projections $\{p_n\}$ form an approximate unit for $\mathbb{K}(\ell^2)$, so every $x\in\mathbb{K}(\ell^2)$ satisfies $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}p_nxp_n$. So it suffices to show that $p_nxp_n\in C^*(E)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{K}(\ell^2)$.

More generally, if $\{e_k\}$ is the canonical orthonormal basis of $\ell^2$, we define $y_{i,j}:\ell^2\to \ell^2$ by $y_{i,j}(\xi)=\langle \xi,e_j\rangle e_i$. Observe that $p_n=\sum_{i=1}^ny_{i,i}$. Moreover, $$p_1=y_{1,1}=I-TT^*\in C^*(E)$$ and also $$y_{i,j}=T^{j-1}\cdot p_1\cdot (T^*)^{i-1}\in C^*(E)$$
for all $i,j$. Now it is easy to verify that $p_n\cdot\mathbb{B}(\ell^2)\cdot p_n=\text{span}\{y_{i,j}: 1\leq i,j\leq n\}$, so $p_n\cdot\mathbb{B}(\ell^2)\cdot p_n\subset C^*(E)$ for all $n$. This shows that $p_nxp_n\in C^*(E)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{K}(\ell^2)$ and all $n\geq1$, so, since $C^*(E)$ is closed, we have that $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}p_nxp_n\in C^*(E)$ and the claim is proved.

Comment: My answer is basically the details to what Mike F describes in their answer. I am posting this because OP asks for "a more detailed answer".

Comment: Thank you for your answer! May I ask what is $C^*(E)$?

Comment: @Korn it is the C-star algebra generated by E, i.e the least c star algebra containing E (the closure of polynomials in two non commuting variables applied to T anD T*)